# Will performance vary depends on 32bit/64 bit IEDriverServer in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

For IE10,with IEdriverserver 2.42.0(64 bit) the sendkeys command is executed very slow(almost taking 3-4seconds to type each character).I tried with 32 bit IEDriverserver 2.42.0.The problem got resolved.
Just wanted to know,whether there will be any performance issue If I use 32 bit version instead of 64 bit.My machine is 64bit windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

I mainly use IE9 and there is a big difference between 32bit and 64bit drivers versions.
As far as I remember due to JavaScript handling which was introduced only in 32bit. Anyway this should be OK with IE10 but is not - there is a performance issue reported [here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5116&sort=-stars&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary)
btw:Try to paste string or use JavaScriptExecutor to set an element's value in case longer strings instead of using SendKeys. This should be much faster.

Comment: The issue that everyone seems to overlook with this is that when you're running 64-bit Windows, with IE 10 or higher, even if you think you've started 64-bit Internet Explorer, you really haven't. [Comment 21](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5116#c21) points out the root cause in excruciating detail, including information about the mixed 32-bit/64-bit nature of IE 10 and later.